# How to get specific properties from a REST JSON response using Httpfull in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, webserver

I want to show the name, city, etc. and I don't want to show all the data just some of it.

```
<?php    
 $url='my url';
$res = \Httpful\Request::get($url)->expectsJson()->send();
$data = json_decode($res,true);
print_r($data);  ?>
```

The output is:

> Array ( [message] => OK [property] => Array ( [id] => 193547
>   [broker_id] => 4772 [second_broker_id] => 7530 [third_broker_id] =>
>   4695 [address] => 534 Canyon Drive [city] => Eyota [state] => MN [zip]
>   => 55934 [county] => Olmsted [market] => [submarket] => [cross_streets] => [location_description] => The Subject Property is
>   positioned along Hwy 42, the road from Interstate 90 heading into
>   Eyota. Adjacent to the property is a 34-unit assisted living/memory
>   care center, as well as a small residential development. Less than 1
>   mile away is the city’s West Side Park, which has 2 baseball fields, a
>   skate park, sand volleyball courts and it even hosts a farmers market
>   during warmer summer months. Eyota has a population of 2,025 and is
>   just 13 miles east of Rochester, which has a population of 100,000.
>   [latitude] => 43.995568 [longitude] => -92.24475 [name] => Dollar
>   General #17079 [property_type_id] => 2 [property_subtype_id] => 203
>   [additional_property_subtype_ids] => Array ( )

Comment: Print $data and see attribute which you want to show

Comment: Can you please show me your data output?

Comment: i do this but it will show all the data i just want to show name and city from it so ?

Comment: @MohammadArifMaseed It's impossible to give an answer with the information you provided. Please edit the question and copy and past the output of your script into it.

Comment: see the output i just want to show the name and address ?

Comment: sir waiting for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want specific data only directly access it with key.

As per your example:

```
$data = json_decode($res,true);
$name =  $data['properties'][0]['name'];
$city =  $data['properties'][0]['city'];
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: property in C:\xampp\htdocs\arif\index.php on line 9

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: property in C:\xampp\htdocs\arif\index.php on line 10

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\arif\index.php on line 12

Comment: it give this three error

Comment: SIR I WANT TO  show the all the names and citys in [0],[1],[2] so how can do that

Comment: Thank you sir love you God Bless you it work perfect

Comment: sir it works. just need little more help sir how to show this data in table ?

Comment: `echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>City</th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$city</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";`

Comment: sir how to show image ?

Comment: sir just remaining to display image sir plx i need your help sir plz ??????

Comment: `foreach ($arr['properties'][0]['photos'] as $photo) {
  echo '<img src="'.$photo['url'].'">';
}`

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\arif\khan.php on line 18

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: arr in C:\xampp\htdocs\arif\khan.php on line 18

Comment: sir what can i do with this warning

Comment: change `$arr` to `$data`. Also first learn basic PHP

Comment: thank you sir it has 7 picture   i want to display only one picture ???

Comment: sir how to call picture bi id ?

Comment: how to show image by id